# Span element is clipped of after animation starts

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a span element thats inside a div. I set the div css property overflow to none, and yet when animation starts the span element is clipped off.

I would like for the span element to not be clipped off and stay the same when animation starts and when done.

Am I missing something, or am I forgetting something? I've been trying to fix this for the past couple of hours and yet to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Here's the jfiddle link.

[jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka3Pn/18/)

The span element is the "5", hover over the error div to start animation.

Comment: FYI: `none` is not a valid value for overflow, but I actually don't think it's affecting anything here anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery adds an `overflow:hidden` when it does animations, so you can't animate the entire container in this case.  Try:

http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/Ka3Pn/19/